# how to disable the arrow keys of android keyboard

Tags: android, emulation

im displaying web page content in webview and i want to disable the all 4 arrow key of android keyboard. any idea?

edit:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    int a;
     Log.d("yourTag",""+event.getAction());
    System.out.println(a=event.getAction());
    System.out.println(keyCode);
      if(event.getAction()==20){
         return true;
      }
      else if(event.getAction()==21){
          return true;
      }
      else if(event.getAction()==22){
          return true;
      }
      else{
              return true;
      }

    }
```

scrolling still there but back key and menu key is disabled why? i noticed it returns nothing if content is scrolling. once scrolling ends it(log.d message) returns 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch them in an onkeydown?

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
  if(event.getAction() == /*INSERT YOUR KEY*/){
    //do something with the arrows. or ignore them
    //return true or false depending on if you want to "catch" the event i guess
  }else{
      return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
  }
}
```

You'd only have to find the code for the arrow-keys, that shouldn't be to hard. You could even just Log.d your `event.getAction()`, and press them, to find out what they're called...

I don't really know what you are doing with your debugcode, but check out this link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html for the key events. The events are integers. Why don't you add this for debugging:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    Log.d("yourTag",""+event.getAction());
}
```

and see what's returned? My guess would be one of the [DPAD](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT) keys, for instance left ( 21 ) are your target

Comment: @Nanne it returns 0 for two arrow keys and nothing returna for antohr 2  arrow keys... i did like this.. System.out.println(a=event.getAction());
     
       if(event.getAction()==a){
       
        System.out.println(a); return true;
                  
       }else{
        System.out.println(" displaying else");
           return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
       }
     
     }

Comment: @Naane yesyou are right .  but i  want to disable scrolling of pressing these key buttons. how can i do that?

Comment: Well, if you DON't call `super.onKeyDown` for those keys, they are effectively blocked. They don't do anything, so they shouldn't scroll. Because all the other keys don't 'match' your `if`, they get passed on to super.onKeyDown(). Return for your dpad things `true` to indicate you've handled the event.

Comment: @Nanne im unable to stop scrolling. pls see my edited question.

Comment: You don't seem to call super.onKeyDown at all, so it's would really surprise me if your keys do anything at all. Are you sure this code gets called, and you have it in the correct file and all?

Comment: @Nanne yeah you are right  back key and menu key are blocked.